# Adding currently visited SE site to "Your communities" link

Tags: feature-request, communities-list

I would like to add the currently visited SE site to the "Your communities" section of the StackExchange (top-left) dropdown.

I suggest adding a link next to "chat blog logout" saying "add to list" or similar so that you do not have to type in the name and add it manually. This would speed up tracking Area51 sites considerably.

Comment: Having it always near the "chat", "blog" etc is too intrusive in my opinion, better have it somewhere else e.g. below the list besides the "reset" link, something like "add current".

Comment: There could be an "Actions..." dropdown ("dropping" to the right) in place of "chat blog logout"... and then additional actions could be listed there.

Comment: Nah, can't see any point for this, at least until we'll have more "generic" actions fitting all users. I'm not against your request, just not for it as well in its current form.